# Why do the range of values change when I export geostatistical layer to raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst, interpolation

I did an interpolation of soil pH using 232 data points in geostatistical analyst with IDW, RBF and ordinary kriging. For all 3 methods, the range of pH values change (become smaller) after I export the geostatistical layers to raster. I understand that has something to do with the way values are calculated per cell in raster, but is there a way I could keep the pH range in the output raster?

Answer (score 1):

The conversion of a geostatistical model to a raster will discretize the support (creating pixels). The value of the pixels will be defined at their center, so if the maximum/minimum is not at the center of a pixel, it will not be stored in the raster. If you want to be closer to the values, you will need to take a smaller pixel size.

Comment: You can also use a different cells assignment type (e.g. MEAN or MAX or MIN or RANGE) -- this will only be the statistics per cell, however, not per raster.

Comment: I see @radouxju. unfortunately my resolution can't be better because of my other datasets :(

Comment: @Erica: do I change the cell assignment type under 'environment'? but what do u mean when u say the statistics is per cell (pixel?) not per raster?

Comment: It's part of the [Point to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000002z000000) tool options. This setting determines how the raster cell is assigned a value -- the default is "most common" (say, points of 5, 5, 10, the raster cell is then 5), or if it has two values (say, 5 and 10) it will randomly pick one. Using a different assignment type can give more control over how the values are assigned. Only way to ensure every point is represented is with smaller pixels, as @radouxju has said.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand that. but the geostatistical layer is not a shapefile with points, so how can I do the cell assignment? I don't find it in the 'environments' when I export it to raster. And I also tried reducing the output cell size when I exported the geostatistical layer to raster, but the range got even smaller actually. Am I doing something wrongly??

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem already?

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem yet? GA Layers when exported to Raster has a very different range of values

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting your prediction as a vector using filled contours. Then convert the vector back to a raster layer using the polygon to raster tool.